When a user is suspended, how about putting that fact underneath their icon so they're not shocked by their points suddenly being 1?
Normal people make correct inferences about the actions of others, but when I was suspended, I saw the 1 point, and was very confused. I hadn't yet read the mod message, I thought maybe my points were lost into what we used to call the bit bucket.
I had to search around and finally ask someone in another stack what happened.
Now, the same problem is different. I'm suspended so frequently that twice, I answered someone's question with a complex answer, and when I clicked Post, it spit in my face.
Just put the word "suspended" in tiny letters underneath their icon.
It could even be a link to further information about suspension. You should probably do that under every occurrence of the avatar of a suspended user, so others will know their shame.

"You should probably do that under every occurrence of the avatar of a suspended user, so others will know their shame." no. I see no reason to do that.

It is weird, I must admit, that suspended users can still see the answer box and type answers, and only when they hit "Submit" do they get told that they can't answer due to being suspended. I do wonder if that aspect of the UX could be improved.

Or simply don't reduce reputation to 1 for suspended users. I don't see a convincing benefit in doing that, and it does potentially draw attention and confuses users. Suspensions are not intended to shame the users, so your idea would be counterproductive.

@F1Krazy My impression is that it's bad design on purpose.

How does your suggestion (banner on icon) actually help address the usage problem (posting without being aware of ban)? The user icon is very far away from the focus leading to the answer text area. It’s only a tiny part in the header.

This is NOT the place to discuss whether your suspensions were rightly or wrongly issued, or whether more will follow. So keep that out of your post. If you do want to have that discussion, use the [Contact] option at the bottom of each page and take it up with staff.

@MissUnderstands The "I see no reason to do that" remark was specifically about your suggestion to add a conspicuous note so that "others will know [the suspended user's] shame". Suspensions are not stocks, and we have rules to prevent discussions of suspensions unless the suspended user brings it up (and especially while the suspended user is suspended, and can't participate) – except where moderator misconduct is alleged, in which case there are other procedures. The other points you raise are relevant, and those certainly have not been shut down.

@MissUnderstands Your perception is incorrect, but it is a valid interpretation of the information you have been provided. That you feel this way about suspensions is a significant UX bug, in my opinion. I think your suggestion (put the word "suspended" in the same place as the 1 reputation) is very sensible – though I'd put it beside the 1 instead of under the icon.

@MissUnderstands I quoted the part that I disagreed with. Please don't try and twist this into something it wasn't.

Changing the reputation counter to 1 during a suspension happens for technical reasons (site privileges are hardcoded based on the reputation counter, so the only way to remove those privileges used to be to override the reputation counter). It's a long-standing problem – but it's something I'd personally got used to, and forgotten about. I'm glad you've re-raised the issue.

I think this feature request should be split into two: one about showing a "suspended" notice alongside the 1 reputation, and another about the answer being rejected after you'd written it.

@MissUnderstands Understood. Do you mind if somebody else makes those posts (with credit)?

@wizzwizz4 well one 1 rep users can post though…why isn’t it reduced internally to 0 but externally shows normally

@Starship It also applies a question and answer ban. As for why: historical and technical reasons. You can write up a separate feature request, if you like.

@Starship Its 1 cause Jeff decided no one's rep should go below 1. And practically, I believe that suspensions just 'flip' the "can't post question/answer" bits

@JourneymanGeek And prevent editing or suggested editing and say they will prevent you from following posts (but doesn’t actually).

following posts is 'newer' so possibly not Jeff's fault :D

As a suspended user - you will get

An Email
A moderator message

The latter will be an inbox notification
This feels generally sufficient in most cases.
)
You will also see something like this when you click through

This feels generally sufficient to let people know they were suspended, rather than rubbing their nose with it, so to speak.
Maybe have a more obvious sign its a mod message and not a notice, but generally you shouldn't get mod messages too often. If you're suspended frequently - perhaps check your unread messages before you post a complex answer, or better yet... get suspended less frequently, by altering problem behaviours since that's our general goal with suspensions.

You're not supposed to interact with your sock puppets :P

I mean, its a good thing that which mod suspended you is hidden, that way I can't get mad at myself for suspending...myself

2 days I interacted with an experienced user, who, despite having been suspended 15 times, had like 10 expired suspensions after which they contributed to the site, who didn’t know they could post after a suspension. I’d imagine that even with all of this many users will still be confused.

I'm having trouble parsing that...
